# expected ')' before '*' token with function pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters, struct

here is the code:

```
typedef struct {
    void (*drawFunc) ( void* );
} glesContext;

void glesRegisterDrawFunction(glesContext *glesContext, void(drawFunc*)(glesContext*));
```

For that last line, i get the error message: "Expected ')' before '*' token"

why?

Answer (score 5):

You *have* the correct way of doing a function pointer in your `struct` (so kudos for that, so many people get it wrong).

Yet you've swapped around the `drawFunc` and `*` in your function definition, which is one reason why the compiler is complaining. The other reason is that you have the same identifier being used as the type and the variable. You should choose *different* identifiers for the two different things.

Use this instead:

```
void glesRegisterDrawFunction(glesContext *cntxt, void(*drawFunc)(glesContext*));
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
                                                       note here
```

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to add a pointer to function typedef as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    void (*drawFunc) ( void* );
} glesContext;

// define a pointer to function typedef
typedef void (*DRAW_FUNC)(glesContext*);

// now use this typedef to create the function declaration
void glesRegisterDrawFunction(glesContext *glesContext, DRAW_FUNC func);
```

Comment: Typedeffing function pointers can make them easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting this in parentheses: glesContext *glesContext.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your code is trying to do, but if you just want to make it compile, try

```
void glesRegisterDrawFunction(glesContext *glesContext, void (*drawFunc)(glesContext*));
```